# How to organize multiple foreign keys for gorm

Tags: mysql, go, go-gorm

I am making a Go project with gorm for mysql.

When creating a mysql table using gorm, it is necessary to create multiple foreign keys for one table. Until now, it was created like the following code

such a table

```
type Members struct {
    ID           int32     `gorm:"AUTO_INCREMENT" json:"id" from:"id"`
    MyselfUserID int32     `gorm:"NOT NULL" json:"myself_user_id" from:"myself_user_id"` 
    MemberUserID int32     `gorm:"NOT NULL" json:"member_user_id" from:"family_user_id"` 
    FirstName    string    `json:"first_name" from:"first_name"`
    LastName     string    `json:"last_name" from:"last_name"`
    Relationship string    `json:"relationship" from:"relationship"`
    Image        string    `json:"image" from:"image"`                       
    Version      int32     `gorm:"column:version" json:"version" form:"version"`        
    UpdatedAt    time.Time `gorm:"column:updated_at" json:"updated_at" form:"updated_at"`
    CreatedAt    time.Time `gorm:"column:created_at" json:"created_at" form:"created_at"` 
}
```

I had a foreign key like this

```
MgtDB.AutoMigrate(&Members{}).AddForeignKey("myself_user_id", "users(user_id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT").AddForeignKey("member_user_id", "users(user_id)", "RESTRICT", "RESTRICT")
```

I feel a little verbose
Please let me know if there are other ways like this

Thanks

Answer (score -1, accepted):

```
type Members struct {
    ...
    MemberUserID int32
    MemberUser   User   `gorm:"foreignkey:MemberUserID"`
}
```

[document: define a foreign key](https://gorm.io/docs/belongs_to.html#Foreign-Key)